# Error while loading MLFlow model in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, torch, mlflow

I am saving the MLFlow model using databricks. Below are the details:

```
artifact_path: model
databricks_runtime: 8.4.x-gpu-ml-scala2.12
flavors:
  python_function:
    data: data
    env: conda.yaml
    loader_module: mlflow.pytorch
    pickle_module_name: mlflow.pytorch.pickle_module
    python_version: 3.8.8
  pytorch:
    model_data: data
    pytorch_version: 1.9.0+cu102
```

**I am not able to locally load the model using Python 3.7**, whereas it works well with Python 3.9.

Any idea what could be the possible resolution to this?

Error Trace:

```
  File "/Users/danishm/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/__init__.py", line 714, in load_model
    return _load_model(path=torch_model_artifacts_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/danishm/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/pytorch/__init__.py", line 626, in _load_model
    return torch.load(model_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/danishm/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 607, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/Users/danishm/opt/miniconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 882, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
TypeError: code() takes at most 15 arguments (16 given)
```

I have tried specifying the pickle module name explicitly as `mlflow.pytorch.load_model(ML_MODEL_PATH,pickle_module=mlflow.pytorch.pickle_module)`

But still getting the same error.

Comment: please refer to https://github.com/RedisGears/redisgears-py/issues/13, it is strictly connected to python version.

Comment: @s3nh So if I save the MLFlow model in python 3.7, would that work?